# NestJs backend Failed over AppGateway initialization when run docker-compose up -d

Tags: websocket, nestjs, nestjs-socket.io

I have a separate app for Backend(NestJs) and Frontend(AngularJs).

When running backend locally(nest start) then getting success like below :

```
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +104ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:00 pm   [InstanceLoader] ServeStaticModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:04 pm   [InstanceLoader] DatabaseModule dependencies initialized +4300ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:04 pm   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +7ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:04 pm   [InstanceLoader] KudoModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:04 pm   [InstanceLoader] BlogModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:04 pm   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:05 pm   [AppGateway] initialized
[Nest] 51995   - 21/0ee_NDN}\qb#g4Zv"9/2021, 11:17:05 pm   [RoutesResolver] PostController {/api/posts}: +4ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:05 pm   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/posts, GET} route +4ms
[Nest] 51995   - 21/09/2021, 11:17:05 pm   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/posts, POST} route +2ms
```

But when using docker-compose up -d then getting below error :

```
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:05 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:06 AM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1172ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:06 AM   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:06 AM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:06 AM   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +0ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:06 AM   [InstanceLoader] ServeStaticModule dependencies initialized +2ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:07 AM   [InstanceLoader] DatabaseModule dependencies initialized +1005ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:07 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +8ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:07 AM   [InstanceLoader] KudoModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:07 AM   [InstanceLoader] BlogModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend_1  | [Nest] 32   - 09/22/2021, 5:14:07 AM   [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend_1  | (node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: shared_utils_1.addLeadingSlash is not a function
backend_1  |     at SocketServerProvider.validateNamespace (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-server-provider.js:46:31)
backend_1  |     at SocketServerProvider.getServerOfNamespace (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-server-provider.js:40:97)
backend_1  |     at SocketServerProvider.createWithNamespace (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-server-provider.js:33:38)
backend_1  |     at SocketServerProvider.createSocketServer (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-server-provider.js:26:21)
backend_1  |     at SocketServerProvider.scanForSocketServer (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-server-provider.js:17:20)
backend_1  |     at WebSocketsController.subscribeToServerEvents (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:34:60)
backend_1  |     at WebSocketsController.connectGatewayToServer (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:25:14)
backend_1  |     at SocketModule.connectGatewayToServer (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:46:35)
backend_1  |     at /app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:35:38
backend_1  |     at IteratorWithOperators.forEach (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/node_modules/iterare/lib/iterate.js:157:13)
backend_1  | (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
backend_1  | (node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
backend_1  | (node:32) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9PBi.png)

NestJs versions used :

```
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.3.2",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.1.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.0",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^7.3.2",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the very same issue. In fact it all started after adding some namespace to one of my event gateways.
From the error message it looks like it was unable to find some exported utility function from the **shared_utils_1**. After short investigation, it turned out this is being exported as part of the **"nestjs/common"** package. So I looked into the package.json that is being copied as part of the build process to the docker container and noticed that the version for that particular package was different (7.0.9) than the one I used while building the app locally (8.0.0).

I updated the version (8.0.0), rebuild the app, and everything seems to be working ever since.